# Running WebdriverJS test on Selenium Grid

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a Selenium Grid running on AmazonEC2

It consists of a hub running on port 7055 and a node running on port 7056.

I have the following test:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    driver = new webdriver.Builder().
       usingServer('http://ec2-50-18-75-182.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7055/wd/hub').
       withCapabilities({'browserName': 'firefox'}).
       build();


var postTitle = "Post "+(+new Date);

driver.get('http://si-demo.herokuapp.com/posts/new');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('post_name')).sendKeys("Selenium");
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('post_title')).sendKeys(postTitle);
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('post_content')).sendKeys("This is auto generated by a test");
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('commit')).click();
driver.quit();
```

That fails when I try to connect to the hub port. 
The test does run when I connect directly to the node port.

The error I get when connecting to the grid hub is:

```
timers.js:103
            if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
                                                                      ^
Error: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT
    at ClientRequest.sendRequest (/Users/jason/Development/cirrus/spanish-inquisition-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:127:16)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1436:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/Users/jason/Development/cirrus/spanish-inquisition-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:130:49)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/Users/jason/Development/cirrus/spanish-inquisition-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:109:30)
    at Builder.build (/Users/jason/Development/cirrus/spanish-inquisition-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:70:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jason/Development/cirrus/spanish-inquisition-runner/open_canvas.js:5:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

**My question is:**
Does Selenium WebdriverJS support connecting to the hub? If so what am I doing wrong?

Notes:

- I have connected to the hub and successfully run the same steps as an rspec test.
- I was also able to connect to the hub locally on the EC2 instance and run the test, only happens when trying to connect remotely to the grid.
- When looking at the Selenium2 grid console at :7055/grid/console it does appear to be using a session on the node.

Commands I used on EC2 to start the grid:

```
Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x768x24 2>&1 >/dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:0
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -port 7055 -role hub
xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:7055/grid/register
```

Comment: Perhaps, when using WebDriver JS, you may need to run a particular version of the Grid Hub?  From their site, it looks like 2.32.0 will work but maybe you should try 2.29 or another version and see if the error changes?

Comment: How sure are you that you opened the ports from your selenium Hub to your EC2 instance?  If it was me, I would run only the Grid Node on the EC2 instance and then I would run the hub on my own computer.

Comment: what is the result of command `curl http://ec2-50-18-75-182.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7055/wd/hub`?

Comment: can you check this url remotely in the browser? It should show you all nodes available for you on the grid `http://ec2-50-18-75-182.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:7055/grid/console`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using remote webdriver?
I haven't used the JS driver, but C# has a specific driver for remote grid connections.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Using_the_Stand-alone_Selenium_Server

Looking at the JS docs, you probably need to do something like this when you construct your driver:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), 
    SeleniumServer = require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer;
```